# Error in endpoint URL Sharepoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I'm using jquery to upload an image in a Sharepoint list.
The file for this image contains a single quote and space.

```
fileName="Test ' ";
var fileCollectionEndpoint = String.format(
                "{0}/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('{1}')/files" +
                "/add(overwrite=true, url='{2}')",
                serverUrl, serverRelativeUrlToFolder, fileName);
return jQuery.ajax(
        url: fileCollectionEndpoint,
        type: "POST",
        data: arrayBuffer,
        processData: false,
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "content-length": arrayBuffer.byteLength
        },
        success: function(result) {
        }
    });
```

The error is

```
{"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"fr-FR","value`enter code here`":"L'expression \u00ab\u00a0web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('bibli_photo_gare')/files/add(overwrite=true, url='test '.jpg')\u00a0\u00bb n'est pas valide."}}}
```

When I delete the space and single quote there is no error.
Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs since a *single quote* character `'` needs to be escaped in OData query like  `''` or `%27%27`

For that matter you could utilize the following function:

```
function encodeName(name){
    var encName = encodeURIComponent(name);
    encName = encName.replace(/'/g, '%27%27');
    return encName;
}
```

Then file name could be provided like this:

```
var fileName = encodeName("Test ' ");
```